# cups-pdf stops working after reboot on ubuntu 13.04

Tags: printing, pdf

my PDF virtual printer installed via
`sudo apt-get install cups-pdf` normally generates pdf files in ~/PDF directory.
However, after reboot, it doesn't work anymore.
Jobs appear to be 'cancelled' in localhost:631.

If I make:

```
sudo dpkg -P cups-pdf
```

and then 
`sudo apt-get install cups-pdf`, it works again!!!

Can someone suggest me a way to solve this annoying problem?

Thanks,
pier

Answer (score 0):

It is completely silly bug and is related to ownership or similar. In any case after reboot cups-pdf gives 2 errors "failed to create directory (/var/spool/cups-pdf)" and "failed to create spool directory (/var/spool/cups-pdf/SPOOL)". These directories are necessary for cups-pdf. If you create these directories manually then cups-pdf works again

In any case I found a solution that I added 2 lines to a startup script in "/etc/init.d/pcscd" (you can use other script too - for exemple "saned"):

```
mkdir /var/spool/cups-pdf
mkdir /var/spool/cups-pdf/SPOOL
```

I added these lines just in the start of the script - immediately after the lines with #

I know it is not correct way to do this but I cannot figure out how to repair this bug.